# Angular Material installation issue - "no such a file or directory"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-material

I am trying to install Angular Material using npm. I have installed Node.js. Whenever i try to install Angular Material using npm command  in the command line I am getting the following error.

> npm WARN enoent :no such a file or directory,open
>   'c:\users\hp\package.json'

is anything missing ???

Comment: First you need to type `npm init` and then `npm install angular-material --save`

Comment: npm init says npm install <pkg> --save what it means ??

Answer (score 1):

The folder you are working on does not seem to be a node project folder. NPM expects a file called package.json to be in the root of your project before it can start installing dependencies.

You can create this file via helper by running `npm init`